# how to Filter by a concatenated group in r

Tags: r

```
boys <- c("Tom", "Dick", "Harry")
```

[image: name: Item: Tom rakes Tom rakes Dick Shovel Sarah pickaxe Wendy hammer Harry tent]

I would like to filter or group by the concatenated list.

I have tried:

```
blue <- names %>% group_by(boys)

blue <- names %>% filter(names == boys)

blue <- names %>% filter(names == c("Tom", "Dick", "Harry"))
```

none work and i am at a loss. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Assuming the data you show is called `my_data`, and the "name:" column is actually called "names" (which seems to be what you are using in your code), `my_data %>% filter(names %in% boys)`.

Comment: And a terminology correction, `boys <- c("Tom", "Dick", "Harry")`, in R, is a *vector*, specifically a `character` vector, not a concatenated list.

Comment: thank you everything worked and thank you for the correction!

Comment: @akrun thanks - I should perhaps get out of the habit of quick comment when it is a full solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering with a set of values in r (dplyr)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55037179/filtering-with-a-set-of-values-in-r-dplyr)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the data you show is called my_data, and the "name:" column is actually called "names" (which seems to be what you are using in your code), try this:

```
my_data %>% filter(names %in% boys)
```